# Can I determine if current test execs from test lab or interactively from within QTP IDE?

Tags: automated-tests, qtp, hp-quality-center

What is the most efficient way to check if the current QTP test execution is interactive, i.e. not part of a QC test set execution launched from the QC test lab?

Do you guys know a cool way? WR used to have a batch run flag which reliably was cleared for all executions from within the IDE. Maybe QTP has something like this, and I overlooked it?

First, I thought about looking at the `OnError` property:

```
Set qtApp = getObject("","QuickTest.Application")
```

`qtApp.Test.Settings.Run.OnError` now returns one of these possible values:
"Dialog", "NextIteration", "Stop" or "NextStep".

This would allow me to look at the `OnError` setting, which probably is <> "Dialog" and <> "Stop" when execution is part of a test set, but:

- I managed to avoid the automation interface in all my QTP tests, this would be my first exception (earlier QTP versions got confused and launched a second QTP instance, creating lots of problems...)
- A tester might do an "interactive" run from within the QTP IDE with this setting set to "NextStep" or "NextIteration", which I then would misinterpret in my code.
- It does not work, even if dialogs are not coming up (due to execution from a QC test set), the value returned is "Dialog". DOH!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No need to go to the automation object, it is exposed in the `Setting` object.

```
If Setting("IsInTestDirectorTest") Then
    Print "Run from QC"
Else
    Print "Not run from QC"
End If
```

Note that TestDirector (TD) is the historical name of QualityCenter (QC).

Comment: Doh. That works perfectly. Where is this documented? If it is not documented, how do you know about it?

Comment: Even google has 0 exact hits for the string IsInTestDirectorTest. WTF?

Comment: @TheBlastOne, I could tell you but then I'd have to recruit you... I'm not sure if this is a supported feature [anyway soon Google should have at least one hit for `IsInTestDirectorTest` :o)].

Comment: Got it, thanx. Duke Nukem would say: "Hehehe, what a mess."

Comment: Addendum: Setting ("IsInTestDirectorTest") returns Empty if execution is not from within a TD/QC/ALM test set, NOT false. (Since empty <> true, this does not matter in the code shown.) Obviously, the setting only exists if...

Comment: *Update* This setting still works with UFT. However, as soon as the UFT instance has executed one test from ALM, the setting always returns 0 (not empty). So this works only if you uncheck "Keep UFT open after a test lab run session ends" in the UFT remote agent settings. Not sure if this should be added to the answer. @Motti I´d vote for doing so.

Answer (score 0):

It might be an option to use

```
Public Function IsTestSetRun ()
    Dim Result: Result=false
    If not QCUtil is Nothing then
        If not QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest is Nothing then
            Result=true
        End If
    End If
    IsTestSetRun=Result
End Function
```

which is based on `QCUtil.CurrentTestSetTest`. Unfortunately, it returns `true` if you run a GUI test interactively, so it is not really a complete solution.

But since the other option does not work with BPT components, I am now using this option.