# How to Flag a custom field in QC to determine if a test has been run through a batch

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-quality-center

I have a classic vbs file to run tests through QC/QTP.
I would like to add a custom field in QC and set that field to yes or 1 when the test is run through the Vbs in contrast to a test run through QC or directly on QTP.

Comment: So what's your problem?

Comment: Thanks for your answer,  I am out of idea how to add this Flag to my batch.

Answer (score 0):

You can try and see if QTP's objects are defined

```
If TypeName(Window) = "Empty" Then
    MsgBox "VBScript"
Else
    MsgBox "QTP"
End If
```

How to distinguish between QTP and QC is [answered here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4177626/3848).